# Can't get TextField to switch focus after pressing next

Tags: swift, swiftui, focus, textfield

I have a list of text views where I would like to switch the focus after the next key has been pressed. I have a struct which represents my text field data:

```
struct WordEntry : BaseIndexStruct, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable{
    let id = UUID()
    var word : String = ""
    var index : Int
    
    init(index: Int) {
        self.index = index
    }
}
```

I then have a view for a text field where the focus is controlled, I added a print statement here to see if `word.index == focus!` is ever actually `true`. It does become `true` but setting the `isFocused` has no impact and during the print it is still `false`.

```
struct SolvedField: View {
    @State var word: WordEntry
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @Binding var focus: Int?
    var nextFocus: (Int) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $word.word)
            .onChange(of: focus, perform: { newValue in
                if(focus != nil){
                    self.isFocused = word.index == focus!
                    print("index \(word.index), focus \(focus!), isfocused: \(self.isFocused) should be focused \(word.index == focus!)")
                }
            })
            .focused(self.$isFocused)
            .submitLabel(.next)
            .onSubmit {
                isFocused = false
                self.nextFocus(word.index)
            }
    }
}
```

and then a view which contains a list of word entries which are then shown as the text field control.

```
struct SolvedLettersLine: View {
    @State var words = [WordEntry(index: 0), WordEntry(index: 1), WordEntry(index: 2), WordEntry(index: 3)]
    @State var focus : Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:10){
            Group{
                ForEach(words) { word in
                    SolvedField(word: word, focus: $focus, nextFocus:{
                        focus = $0 + 1
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am completely stuck on how to get iOS to switch textfield focus to work, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have just one `@FocusState` in `SolvedLettersLine`, that represents which field is currently focused. This should be of type `Int?`.

You can now use the [`focused(_:equals:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focused(_:equals:)) modifier to control the focus of text fields.

Then, you can pass this `@FocusState` to `SolvedField` as a `FocusState.Binding`, similar to how you would pass a regular `@State` to a `@Binding`.

```
struct SolvedField: View {
    // side note: word should not be a @State!
    @Binding var word: WordEntry

    @FocusState.Binding var focus: Int?
    let nextFocus: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $word.word)
            .focused($focus, equals: word.index)
            .submitLabel(.next)
            .onSubmit {
                nextFocus()
            }
    }
}

struct SolvedLettersLine: View {
    @State var words = [WordEntry(index: 0), WordEntry(index: 1), WordEntry(index: 2), WordEntry(index: 3)]
    @FocusState var focus: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:10){
            ForEach($words) { $word in
                SolvedField(word: $word, focus: $focus) { 
                    focus? += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```